# How to keep only the object with the maximum value in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an `ArrayList`. It is in the following format.

```
List interval = new ArrayList<Counter>();

    public class Counter {
       private int start;
       private int end;
       private int count;
       .....
     }
```

```
Start| End | Count
 1    |  2  | 2
 5    |  6  | 1
 1    |  2  | 2
 7    |  8  | 1
 1    |  2  | 3
```

The ArrayList might contain duplicate elements like in here 1 and 2 for start and end respectively.  If there are duplicate elements in the list, I want to keep only the one the maximum value for count and discard others.

```
Start| End | Count
 5    |  6  | 1
 7    |  8  | 1
 1    |  2  | 3
```

This is the result that I am expecting. How can it be done ?

Comment: If this data is coming from a database then you should absolutely be handling it there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not, it is not coming from a database.

Comment: Contrary to what @Turing85 appears to be hinting, [there is no ban on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). If this is one, though, it is helpful to label it as such.  And you should definitely show what you've tried, and you should expect hints in return, not complete answers.

Comment: @Choirbean I did not hint at anything, and especially not that homework questions are banned. Otherwise I would have voted to close this question.

Comment: @Choirbean: While homework questions are allowed, without showing an attempt, without using this attempt the question remains too broad and a valid argument can be made for closing it for this reason. Also as per meta discussions, it is generally expected for homework posters to show the fruits of their efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working.

```
List<Counter> toRemove = new ArrayList<Counter>();

Collections.sort(interval, (first, second) -> {

        int c = 0;

        if (first.compareWith(second)) {
            if (first.getCount() <= second.getCount()())
                toRemove.add(first);
            else if (first.getCount() >= second.getCount())
                toRemove.add(second);
        } else 
            c = first.getCount().compareTo(second.getCount());

        return c;
    }
);

interval.removeAll(toRemove);
```

This is the `compareWith` function in the `Counter` class.

```
public boolean compareWith(Counter second) {

    if (this.getStart().equals(second.getStart()) 
            && this.getEnd().equals(second.getEnd())
            && this.getStart().equals(second.getEnd())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to loop through your ArrayList and check duplicate ones.

```
ArrayList<Counter> interval = new ArrayList<Counter>();
    ArrayList<Counter> interval2 = new ArrayList<Counter>();

        for (int i = 0; i < interval.size(); i++) {

            Counter counteri = interval.get(i);
            int c = 1;
            for (int j = i; j < interval.size()-1; j++) {

                Counter counterj = interval.get(j); 
                int diffStart = counteri.start - counterj.start;
                int diffEnd = counteri.end - counterj.end;

                if(diffStart == 0 && diffEnd == 0){

                    c++;
                }
            }
            counteri.setCount(c);
            interval2.add(counteri);
        }
```